# mailto lotus notes issue with mail toaddress

Tags: lotus-notes, mailto

I was trying to set mailto in our website.

I have written code like below

```
<a href="mailto:mail.us.asc@gmail.com&subject=Profil%20anfordern&body=Guten Tag Herr Peter ManiIhr kundenfreundliches Angebot, mit einem einzigen Klick mehr über eine Bewerbung zu erfahren, nehme ich gerne an. Bitte senden Sie mir weitere Informationen zum Profil.Kand-Nr. 3055, PersonalleitungVielen Dank und freundliche Grüsse">mail us</a>
```

When someone press the Link "mail us", in Lotus Notes the text appears directly where the e-mail address stands.

mail.us.asc@gmail.com&subject=Profil anfordern&body=Guten Tag Herr Peter ManiIhr kundenfreundliches Angebot, mit einem einzigen Klick mehr über eine Bewerbung zu erfahren, nehme ich gerne an. Bitte senden Sie mir weitere Informationen zum Profil.Kand-Nr. 3055, PersonalleitungVielen Dank und freundliche Grüsse

Any help?

Comment: Of course, that only works if the user has a default mail client set, and if that mail client supports passing subject/body fields to it.
Since you are building it in Notes, why not use a real form and submit the data that way?

Answer (score 2):

Use `?` instead of `&` to mark the start of parameters for the mailto link:

```
<a href="mailto:mail.us.asc@gmail.com?subject=Profil%20anfordern&body=Guten Tag Herr Peter ManiIhr kundenfreundliches Angebot, mit einem einzigen Klick mehr über eine Bewerbung zu erfahren, nehme ich gerne an. Bitte senden Sie mir weitere Informationen zum Profil.Kand-Nr. 3055, PersonalleitungVielen Dank und freundliche Grüsse">mail us</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing....

i also tried that but it is not working in lotus notes whereas its working with outlook..

Answer (score 1):

You must use the character `?` as for the parameters of a URL address.

This [link](http://rumkin.com/tools/mailto_encoder/custom.php) can help you and simplify your work in composing the url to use email address encoders. I have also tested on Lotus Notes.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

NOT TESTED. I think you need to add `?` for first query string. Instead of `&subject` change to `?subject` and try

```
<a href="mailto:mail.us.asc@gmail.com?subject=Profil%20anfordern&body=Guten Tag Herr Peter ManiIhr kundenfreundliches Angebot, mit einem einzigen Klick mehr über eine Bewerbung zu erfahren, nehme ich gerne an. Bitte senden Sie mir weitere Informationen zum Profil.Kand-Nr. 3055, PersonalleitungVielen Dank und freundliche Grüsse">mail us</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing....

i also tried that but it is not working in lotus whereas its working with outlook..

Comment: hi, MY CODE is exactly like ::::::: <a mailto:profil_anfordern@almopersonal.ch?subject=Profil%20anfordern&body=Guten%20Tag%20Herr%20Leiter%20Finanz-%20und%20Rechnungswesen%0D%0AIhr%20kundenfreundliches%20Angebot,%20mit%20einem%20einzigen%20Klick%20mehr%20über%20eine%20Bewerbung%20zu%20erfahren,%20nehme%20ich%20gerne%20an.%20Bitte%20senden%20Sie%20mir%20weitere%20Informationen%20zum%20Profil.%0D%0AKand-Nr.%2006643, Leitung%20Rechnungswesen%20/%20CFO%0D%0AVielen%20Dank%20und%20freundliche%20Grüsse%0D%0A>click here to contact</a>     . This is not working with lotus notes.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `?` instead of `&` as described by Per and Muthu works with Lotus Notes 8.5.3 on Windows.

The code

```
<a href="mailto:infobot@example.com?subject=Profil%20anfordern&body=Guten Tag Herr Peter ManiIhr kundenfreundliches Angebot, mit einem einzigen Klick mehr über eine Bewerbung zu erfahren, nehme ich gerne an. Bitte senden Sie mir weitere Informationen zum Profil.Kand-Nr. 3055, PersonalleitungVielen Dank und freundliche Grüsse">Mail 2</a>
```

results, after the link being clicked, in a Lotus Notes Mail being generated:
[image: Screenshot Notes Client with generated mail]

If you are still having problems after replacing the first `&` with `?`, please describe the problem in more detail.