# lotus notes - mailto link issue

Tags: javascript, html, email, lotus-notes, mailto

I am trying to get a mailto link working, but I'm having issues with lotus notes.

My link: `<a href="mailto:?subject=mySubject&body=myBody">Link</a>`

What happens is that the following appears in the subject of the email:
mySubject&body=myBody

It doesn't seem to recognize the &body=

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Can this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777334/mailto-lotus-notes-issue-with-mail-toaddress

Comment: Yes, apparently lotus notes uses ? as a delimeter ... and doesn't recognize &. ... THANKS!!!

Comment: Good to hear. I have added my answer as a real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have universally solved the issue.

The actual reason things were getting messed up is that in the body of my email I had a link. It contained a query string (for example: http://www.aaa.com/index.php?date=xxx&value=yyy)

This & in the link caused the issue!!! It seems that lotus notes explodes/splits the mailto string differently than outlook, and this extra ampersand was not understood.

The solution was to encode the query string so there were no &'s appearing in the body!!!

e.g. `<a href="mailto:?subject=mySubject&body=myBody%0A%0Ahttp://www.aaa.com/index.php?SxgftrTr65bfi">Link</a>`

This works in both lotus and outlook!

NOTE: *SxgftrTr65bfi* would be decoded on the server side!

-Chris

Answer (score 1):

Use `?` instead of `&` to mark the start of parameters for the mailto link.

See this duplicate question: [mailto lotus notes issue with mail toaddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777334/mailto-lotus-notes-issue-with-mail-toaddress)

Comment: This solution very specific to lotus notes and does work! But, I have solved the issue universally ... [see my answer below].

Answer (score 0):

If you have an older version, you may be hitting a bug:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21087914

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, where Lotus notes did not like either question marks (?) or ampersands (&) in the body of an email. Rather than using server-side processing, you can simply replace all question marks in and ampersands with their hex code equivalent.

Use %3F for question marks, and %26 for ampersands, and you should be good to go.